# Difference between "mysql" and "mysql-server" packages/binaries?

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2

I am trying to install MYSQL in amazon ec2. I  was going through some articals on the web and i cannot find the different between these two command

sudo yum install mysql-server
sudo yum install mysql

Can somebody throw some light on this?

Answer (score 3):

`mysql` is the command line client for sending commands to the server. `mysql-server` would be the server/daemon that sits there and responds to your requests and commands.

Comment: NO. When ran the command "sudo yum install mysql" it installed mysql.

Comment: It is possible that mysql-server is marked as a dependency for mysql.